# template and executable file

Tags: c++, templates

Is it true that template code compiled and linked into a PE will increase in size compared to code without templates. I think each instances of templates used is packed orderly so it will output a match if required faster.

Sorry for the question I just don't know much about template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ works on the principle:
**You pay for what you use**.
Template code creates binaries only for the code that you use/Instantiate.

Just because you compile against Standard Library which has hundreds of STL containers it does not mean your object code includes all of them, It only includes the ones you use.

Templates implement compile time polymorphism. An copy of templated function is created for every instantiation you do with different data type, same is the case for templated classes. This code is further compiled to create binaries. So the size of the binary will not be any bigger than what your code without templates would produce.

Comment: Thank you Als, That means the type is ignored, doesn't that ?

Comment: @Baby Dolphin: It matters, A copy of templated function/Class is generated for each *type* please check the updated answer.

Comment: @Baby - On the other hand, if you didn't have templates you would have to write the code once for each type yourself.

Answer (score 3):

The template itself doesn't take any space at all. It the instantiations of that template that do. A template is instantiated once you use it with a type parameter - `MyClass<int> mc`. An instantiation is created once for every type you use, so `MyClass<int> mc2` won't cause another instantiation, but rather use the existing one.

So it really depends on how many types you use with the templates. But that's no different that using different non-templated classes, which will also increase your code size. Bottom line - I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: But what if you say `MyClass<int>` in multiple translation units? Will there be repeated code? Is that where LTO makes a difference?

Comment: No, the implementation has to remove duplicates (using unspecified magic). LTO is more about optimizing across file boundaries.

Comment: @Baby, LTO is [Link Time Optimization](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/LTO.html). The unspecified magic refers to the way the linker removes duplicate instantiations, if they exist on different compilation units - If there's `MC<int>` in two cpp files, will the template be instantiated on both? And if so, will both exist in the final exe, contradicting what I wrote above? The answer to the latter is of course not... :) Duplicate instantiations must be eliminated, but how depends on the compiler's implementation.

Comment: @eran: That's not true. They _may_ be eliminated, but need not. The only requirement is that pointers to the same method compare equal. With inlining, in fact, multiple copies will exist, possibly even withing a single TU.

Comment: @MSalters: I think that `eran` refers to the fact that the symbols cannot be duplicated in the resulting library/executable. Inlining *will* duplicate the code, but *not* the functions/classes.

Comment: @Matthieu: Why would that be impossible? Besides, "classes" generally don't appear in executables as such.

Comment: @MSalters: In general ? I don't care. In practice, the linker takes advantage of the One Definition Rule. However the same symbol may appear multiple times, one per DLL (though DLL already save memory by being shared). Classes per se do not appear, but because of RTTI you have information generated on a per class basis (for those with virtual methods).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to answers given by @Als and @eran:

Compiler and Linker would work collectively to find out code that is same for two or different data types for given class/functions, and if they find out similar code, that is **not-dependent** on datatype, they may create one copy of that code. The code might be a method of class, certain function or some part of method/function.

Comment: Thank you Ajay. 'd like ask more but I'm sleepy now. it's 3:50 and I have not slept the whole day or I will get sick. See you and every one there some hours later.

Comment: Wrong way around, at least how I read it. If `void MC<int>::foo()` is identical to `void MC<int>::bar()` and `void MC<float>::baz()`, then the linker must ensure that `&MC<int>::foo != &MC<int>::bar`. But because you can't compare `void MC<int>::*(void)` and `void MC<float>::*(void)` pointers, it may eliminate `void MC<float>::baz()`. You can't compare legally pointers and notice that.

Comment: I did not say if two functions are identical. I said if implementaion of same function, for two/more datatype is same (or part of it) - then compiler/linker may use the same code-segment instead of making redundant assembly for the same.